# How to update a single value of an object that is inside an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update a specific value inside an object that is inside an array of objects.
Example:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        service: 1001,
        country: {
            id: 1,
            countryname: India
        },
        ts: 1597758281
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        service: 1002,
        country: {
            id: 2,
            countryname: USA
        },
        ts: 1597758283
    }
]
```

Now, I want to update the value of country's id of the first object, so it would become like:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        service: 1001,
        country: {
            id: 2,
            countryname: USA
        },
        ts: 1597758281
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        service: 1002,
        country: {
            id: 2,
            countryname: USA
        },
        ts: 1597758283
    }
]
```

This is what I have tried so far, I am getting the index of the item that is to be updated. Then I've created a copy of the original array and then trying to update the value. But it doesn't seem to work.

```
handleUpdate = (event, item) => {
        const elementsIndex = this.state.laneArray.findIndex(element => element.id == item.id);

        let newArray = [...this.state.laneArray]

        if (event.target.name === "countryName") {
            newArray[elementsIndex] = { ...newArray[elementsIndex], [newArray[0].country.id]: event.target.value }
        }

        this.setState({
            laneArray: newArray,
        });
    }
```

I think I need to update the entire country object. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the index, slice the array before and after that index, and in the middle, set the `country` property to an object with the new ID and with the existing `countryname`:

```js
const input = [
    {
        id: 1,
        service: 1001,
        country: {
            id: 1,
            countryname: 'India'
        },
        ts: 1597758281
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        service: 1002,
        country: {
            id: 2,
            countryname: 'USA'
        },
        ts: 1597758283
    }
];
const i = 0;
const newId = 2;

const output = [
  ...input.slice(0, i),
  {
    ...input[i],
    country: { id: newId, countryname: input[i].country.countryname }
  },
  ...input.slice(i + 1),
];
console.log(output);
```

Also keep in mind that string literals require delimiters, like `'` or `"` or backticks.